# XML Declaration and conversion

Tags: c#, xml, declaration

I'm getting an xml file that I want to convert to UTF-8 from ansi. Initially my code was working because the original xml file didnot have an xml declaration. but recently that the original xml file comes with the following declaration:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1256"?>
```

In my code I'm doing the conversion from ansi to uft-8 and adding another header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

So after I pass the new file through my code for conversion to utf-8, the new declaration is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1256"?>
```

which i believe is invalid.

Below is my code:

```
Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(false);
Encoding ansi = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

string xml = File.ReadAllText(FileName,ansi);
//   XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
//  Console.WriteLine("1st");
File.WriteAllText(
      FileName,
      @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" +  xml.ToString(),
      utf8
);


if (File.Exists(destinationFile))
    File.Delete(destinationFile);

File.Copy(FileName, destinationFile,true);
Console.WriteLine("File Copied" + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt")); // for troubleshoooting only
Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit."); 
Console.Write(CrL);
```

The output of this coming out as garbled arabic text with two declarations. Where am I wrong in the code.

Comment: Any other solutions I can try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly constructing XML with string.Concat is very hard and requires deep understanding of the specification to be done correctly. Unfortunately with reading the specification comes understanding that specialized APIs are much more suitable to manipuulate XML - so no real answer to your question is possible.

Instead please consider using regular Xml APIs - `XmlDocument` or  `XDocument` both would work fine in your case. To save file in encoding of your choice you just need to create XmlWriter with encoding you like as covered in [XmlWriterSettings.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.encoding.aspx).

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(FileName);
```

Save the document to a file using XmlWriter with settings.

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings{Encoding=Encoding.UTF8};
using(var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(destinationFile))
{
  using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileStream, settings))  
  {
    doc.Save(writer);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: cannot convert from 'System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings' to 'System.Text.Encoding'

Comment: Thanks for that, but for some reason the output file in not in UTF-8 encoding. Why is that ? I have cross verfied this the output file remains ansi. There is no conversion happening with the above code

Comment: @user726720 What do you mean "remains ansi"? (I've removed XmlTextWriter version that did not work like I expected...)

Comment: Yes, I got confused. Actually I have a habit of using notepad++. In the encoding in notepadd++ it's not showing the encoding. But if I open in notepad it is showing me utf-8. I have added to the settings to ident, as the above code give's me the results without identation all in one line. This throwing an exception as well: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file. Where as the older version (xmltextwriter), was not throwing this exception.

Comment: The above exception is at the destination and not the source. Do you have any clues to this.

Comment: @user726720, exception is most likly caused by the fact that I did not dispose inner Stream... Updated...

Comment: The exception is still the same

Comment: Hi any clues on the exception.

Comment: Hi This final code doesn't really give me the utf8 as output I have checked it with both notepad and notepad++. Ur older solution one with XMLtextwriter did work but it gave exceptions. Any other solutions to this problem.

Comment: @user726720, I don;t know why you are getting exceptions and really have no idea how you can get non-Utf8 encoded XML using writer configured for Utf8. Consider providing sample that shows your code (with all values as inline strings) in this/new question. I'll delete this answer at some point as it does not work for you.

Comment: the above solution doesnot give me any exceptions but it does not work. When I pass the xml through it. The file remains ansi. I'm using a filesystem watcher with this. As soon as there is a change in xml file it picks up converts to xml and puts it at the destination. Currently it's picking up the file, and putting it at the dest., but at the dest, the file remains ansi and not utf8.

Comment: Okay thanks for all the help, just to inform you that above code works. I had some trouble with the rest of the code (filesystemwatcher). So now it's fixed and the above code is working